# Problem with Double linked list with union as data type in C

Tags: c, file, linked-list, unions

I need to create a double linked list from data in a file with "union" as data type.

### **
this the structure of the Union and node

**

```
union val_t{
    int as_int;
    double as_double;
    char *as_str;
};

struct node_t {
    union val_t *vals;
    struct node_t *prev;
    struct node_t *next;
};
```

Can you help me find the solution to this problem? how can I create my list without the previous values of the list being changed?

**

### This is how i create my list

**

```
int insert(struct list_t *list, union val_t*value){
    if(list==NULL || value==NULL)return 1;
    struct node_t *node = (struct node_t*) malloc(sizeof(struct node_t));
    if(node==NULL)return 2;
    node->vals =value;


    if(list->head==NULL){
        node->next=NULL;
        node->prev=NULL;
        list->head = node;
        list->tail=node;

    } else{
        node->next=NULL;
        node->prev = list->tail;
        list->tail->next = node;
        list->tail = node;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**

### this is how i assign data

**

```
struct list_t{
    struct node_t *head;
    struct node_t *tail;
    struct header_t *header;
};

struct header_t {
    unsigned  int size;
    enum type_t *types;
    char **names;
};

int read_file(struct list_t **list, char *fname){
.
.
.

    while(1){
        
        if(feof(f))break;
        unsigned int i=0;
        char **ptr=NULL;

        while(i<(*list)->header->size){

            fscanf(f,"%s",buf);

            if(feof(f))break;

            if(strlen(buf)>=1){

                if(*(types+i)==1){
                    as_int1 = (int)strtol(buf,ptr,10);
                    (value+i)->as_int = as_int1;
                }

                if(*(types+i)==2){
                    as_double1 = strtod(buf,ptr);
                    ((value+i)->as_double) = as_double1;
                }
                if(*(types+i)==3) {
                    (value + i)->as_str = strdup(buf);
                }
                i++;
            }

        }
  
        if(i>0){
            insert(*list,value);

            if(check==2){
                fclose(f);
                return 2;
            }

        }

    }
.
.
.
}
```

I hope the explanation of my problem is clear.

Thank you for your answers

(Let me know if you need further explanation)

I ask the same question with a code created whith my specific problem. Here's the link. Hope that can help to understand.
[Problem with double linked list with union as data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72807585/problem-with-double-linked-list-with-union-as-data-type)

**

### I find the solution so I will put it here if it can help someone in the future. The problem came from the fact that I did my allocation outside of the loop. So I guess that it was using the same memory every time.

**

**

### Wrong metod :

**

```
int read_file(struct list_t **list, char *fname){
.
.
.
  **
//I did the allocation outside of the loop
union val_t *value = calloc((*list)->header->size, sizeof(union val_t)); 
if(value==NULL){
 fclose(f); 
 free_list(list); 
 return 2; 
}
------------------------------------------------------------------------

**
 while(1){

        if(feof(f))break;
        unsigned int i=0;
        char **ptr=NULL;
      
        while(i<(*list)->header->size){

            fscanf(f,"%s",buf);

            if(feof(f))break;

            if(strlen(buf)>=1){

                if(*(types+i)==1){
                    as_int1 = (int)strtol(buf,ptr,10);
                    (value+i)->as_int = as_int1;
                }

                if(*(types+i)==2){
                    as_double1 = strtod(buf,ptr);
                    ((value+i)->as_double) = as_double1;
                }
                if(*(types+i)==3) {
                    (value + i)->as_str = strdup(buf);
                    if((value + i)->as_str==NULL){
                        fclose(f);
                        free_list(list);
                        return 2;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }

        }

        if(i>0){
           check =  insert(*list,value);

            if(check==2){
                unsigned int j=0;
                while(j<(*list)->header->size){
                    if(*(types+j)==3){
                        free((value+j)->as_str);
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                free(value);
                fclose(f);
                free_list(list);
                return 2;
            }

        }
        else{
            free(value);
        }

    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

**

### GOOD method :

**

```
int read_file(struct list_t **list, char *fname){
.
.
.
  while(1){

        if(feof(f))break;
        unsigned int i=0;
        char **ptr=NULL;
       

**union val_t *value = calloc((*list)->header->size, sizeof(union val_t));**
---------------------------------------------------------------------

        if(value==NULL){
            fclose(f);
            free_list(list);
            return 2;
        }
        while(i<(*list)->header->size){

            fscanf(f,"%s",buf);

            if(feof(f))break;

            if(strlen(buf)>=1){

                if(*(types+i)==1){
                    as_int1 = (int)strtol(buf,ptr,10);
                    (value+i)->as_int = as_int1;
                }

                if(*(types+i)==2){
                    as_double1 = strtod(buf,ptr);
                    ((value+i)->as_double) = as_double1;
                }
                if(*(types+i)==3) {
                    (value + i)->as_str = strdup(buf);
                    if((value + i)->as_str==NULL){
                        fclose(f);
                        free_list(list);
                        return 2;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }

        }

        if(i>0){
           check =  insert(*list,value);

            if(check==2){
                unsigned int j=0;
                while(j<(*list)->header->size){
                    if(*(types+j)==3){
                        free((value+j)->as_str);
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                free(value);
                fclose(f);
                free_list(list);
                return 2;
            }

        }
        else{
            free(value);
        }

    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (!feof`  not good https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong

Comment: You really need to post a [mcve] and a text version of the input file. Then read [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong).

Comment: `insert(*list,value);` I am curious about the type of list, is it  `list **`? why?

Comment: My crystal ball says you're passing a pointer to the same data each time to `insert`.  A [mcve] would tell us for sure.

Comment: The insert method passes this [simple basic test](https://godbolt.org/z/9W7sjn1ad) so the problem must be in how you are using it. I'm still curious about the `*list` thing.

Comment: the question gives us a function of this form ```int read_file(struct list_t **list, char *filename);```

Comment: now that the function signature is available, one more question: are you doing `*list = calloc(1, sizeof(list_t))` at the beginning of the function?

Comment: yes I have  ```*list = (struct list_t*)malloc(sizeof(struct list_t));```

Comment: Joki_004, `fscanf(f,"%s",buf);` is bad.  Post a [mcve] with sample input, output seen and output expected.

Comment: @Joki_004 When examining `.vals`, how do you know what type of data was stored in it?

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica I have an array "type" where is stored the type the value
it is an array of type enum type_t types are always enter the same order

Comment: i posted https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72807585/problem-with-double-linked-list-with-union-as-data-type

Comment: im using fscanf because im basically reading my datas from a file

Comment: I just figure out what was the problem. I alloacte outside of my loop so it was putting my datas in the same memory. Then when I put the allocation in the looped it worked