# Problem with double linked list with union as data type

Tags: c, list, doubly-linked-list, unions

I have to create a list with union as data type but it turns out that after the creation of my list there is only the same value which is repeated on all my list. How Can I handle this?

Can you help me in this direction?

Good day to you

**Structure, Union and Function declaration**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//Declaration of list
struct list_t{
    struct node_t *head;
    struct node_t *tail;
};
struct node_t {
    union val_t *vals;
    struct node_t *prev;
    struct node_t *next;
};

//Declaration of Union
union val_t{
    int as_int;
    double as_double;
    char *as_str;
};
int insert(struct list_t *list, union val_t*value);
```

**Function definition**

```
//Push to create my list
int push_none(struct list_t *list, union val_t*value){
    if(list==NULL || value==NULL)return 1;
    struct node_t *node = (struct node_t*) malloc(sizeof(struct node_t));
    if(node==NULL)return 2;
    node->vals =value;


    if(list->head==NULL){
        node->next=NULL;
        node->prev=NULL;
        list->head = node;
        list->tail=node;

    } else{
        node->next=NULL;
        node->prev = list->tail;
        list->tail->next = node;
        list->tail = node;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Main**

```
int main() {
    //initialization of my list

    struct list_t * list = malloc(sizeof(struct list_t));
    list->tail=NULL;
    list->head=NULL;

    printf("Create a double linked list of 3 element :");
    char buf[100],**ptr=NULL;
    int type[3][3];

    union val_t values[4];
    int as_int1;
    double as_double1;
    int i=0;
    //Data input
    while (i<3){

        int j=0;
        while(j<3){
            while(1){
                printf("\n1 - INT\n2 -DOUBLE\n3 - CHAR\nEnter type:");
                scanf("%d", &type[i][j]);
                if(type[i][j]>0 && type[i][j]<4)break;
            }
            printf("\nEnter value :");
            scanf("%s",buf);

            if(type[i][j]==1){
                as_int1 = (int)strtol(buf,ptr,10);
                (values+j)->as_int = as_int1;
            }
            else if(type[i][j]==2){
                as_double1 = strtod(buf,ptr);
                ((values+j)->as_double) = as_double1;
            }
            else if(type[i][j]==3){
                (values + j)->as_str = strdup(buf);
            }
            j++;
        }
        //Creation of the list
        push_node(list,values);
        i++;
    }
    i=0;
    //Display values
    while(list->head!=NULL){
        int j=0;
        while(j<3){
            if(type[i][j]==1){
                printf("%d ",list->head->vals->as_int);
            }
            if(type[i][j]==2){
                printf("%lf ",list->head->vals->as_double);
            }
            if(type[i][j]==3){
                printf("%s ",list->head->vals->as_str);
            }
            j++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        i++;
        list->head=list->head->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _Side note:_ You probably want to add an `int type;` field to your `struct node_t`

Comment: You need to `malloc` and duplicate the `val_t` array that you store in the node. As you have it the array is stack based so it won't persist and the address is the _same_ for all nodes you create--not what you want. You can have `node_push` do this but you probably want to pass another argument that is the count and add an `int count;` field to the node struct. But if it were me, I would have only one value per node (e.g.) in the node have a value instance and not a pointer. That is simpler and more flexible.

Comment: Thank you I just figure out that I have memory for the array only one times so that why it was assigning only in the same union I don't have 15 of reputation in the order case I would have mark your answer as helpful thank you again

Comment: Alternatively, you could make the node have an instance of the union itself as a member, instead of a pointer to one.  I think it's likely that that was the idea in the first place.  If you do that then you don't need to worry about dynamically allocating the values separately from their nodes.

Comment: Your `as_str` is a bit shady

Comment: @JohnBollinger I got your mind thank you

Comment: @MadPhysicist how ?

Answer (score 2):

This incorporates what I was saying in my top comments.

1. Add `type` to node struct
2. Have an instance of the value in the node struct (*not* a pointer)
3. Only one value per node

Here is the refactored code. It compiles and has been [cursorily] tested:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//Declaration of list
struct list_t {
    struct node_t *head;
    struct node_t *tail;
};

//Declaration of Union
union val_t {
    int as_int;
    double as_double;
    char *as_str;
};

struct node_t {
    int type;
    union val_t vals;
    struct node_t *prev;
    struct node_t *next;
};

int insert(struct list_t *list, union val_t *value);

//Push to create my list
int
push_node(struct list_t *list, union val_t value, int type)
{
    if (list == NULL)
        return 1;

    struct node_t *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (node == NULL)
        return 2;

    node->vals = value;
    node->type = type;

    if (list->head == NULL) {
        node->next = NULL;
        node->prev = NULL;
        list->head = node;
        list->tail = node;

    }
    else {
        node->next = NULL;
        node->prev = list->tail;
        list->tail->next = node;
        list->tail = node;
    }

    return 0;
}

int
main(void)
{

    // initialization of my list
    struct list_t *list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    list->tail = NULL;
    list->head = NULL;

    printf("Create a double linked list of 3 element :");
    char buf[100], **ptr = NULL;
    int type;

    union val_t values;
    int i = 0;

    // Data input
    for (;  i < 3;  ++i) {
        while (1) {
            printf("\n1 - INT\n2 -DOUBLE\n3 - CHAR\nEnter type:");
            scanf("%d", &type);
            if (type > 0 && type < 4)
                break;
        }

        printf("\nEnter value :");
        scanf("%s", buf);

        switch (type) {
        case 1:
            values.as_int = strtol(buf, ptr, 10);
            break;

        case 2:
            values.as_double = strtod(buf, ptr);
            break;

        case 3:
            values.as_str = strdup(buf);
            break;
        }

        // Creation of the list
        push_node(list, values, type);
    }

    // Display values
    for (struct node_t *node = list->head;  node != NULL;  node = node->next) {
        switch (node->type) {
        case 1:
            printf("%d ", node->vals.as_int);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("%f ", node->vals.as_double);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("%s ", node->vals.as_str);
            break;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is some test output:

```
Create a double linked list of 3 element :
1 - INT
2 -DOUBLE
3 - CHAR
Enter type:1

Enter value :23

1 - INT
2 -DOUBLE
3 - CHAR
Enter type:2

Enter value :37.889

1 - INT
2 -DOUBLE
3 - CHAR
Enter type:3

Enter value :jwelrjlewjrowejrowier
23 
37.889000 
jwelrjlewjrowejrowier
```

---

Here is a slightly more cleaned up version. In particular, `node_push` has been simplified:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//Declaration of list
struct list_t {
    struct node_t *head;
    struct node_t *tail;
};

//Declaration of Union
union val_t {
    int as_int;
    double as_double;
    char *as_str;
};

struct node_t {
    int type;
    union val_t vals;
    struct node_t *prev;
    struct node_t *next;
};

int insert(struct list_t *list, union val_t *value);

//Push to create my list
int
push_node(struct list_t *list, union val_t value, int type)
{
    if (list == NULL)
        return 1;

    struct node_t *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (node == NULL)
        return 2;

    node->vals = value;
    node->type = type;

    node->next = NULL;
    node->prev = list->tail;

    if (list->head == NULL)
        list->head = node;
    else
        list->tail->next = node;

    list->tail = node;

    return 0;
}

int
main(void)
{

    // initialization of my list
    struct list_t *list = calloc(1,sizeof(*list));

    printf("Create a double linked list of 3 element :");
    char buf[100], **ptr = NULL;
    int type;

    union val_t values;
    int i = 0;

    // Data input
    for (;  i < 3;  ++i) {
        while (1) {
            printf("\n1 - INT\n2 -DOUBLE\n3 - CHAR\nEnter type:");
            scanf("%d", &type);
            if (type > 0 && type < 4)
                break;
        }

        printf("\nEnter value :");
        scanf("%s", buf);

        switch (type) {
        case 1:
            values.as_int = strtol(buf, ptr, 10);
            break;

        case 2:
            values.as_double = strtod(buf, ptr);
            break;

        case 3:
            values.as_str = strdup(buf);
            break;
        }

        // Creation of the list
        push_node(list, values, type);
    }

    // Display values
    printf("\n");
    printf("List:\n");
    for (struct node_t *node = list->head;  node != NULL;  node = node->next) {
        printf("type: %d ",node->type);

        switch (node->type) {
        case 1:
            printf("%d ", node->vals.as_int);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("%f ", node->vals.as_double);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("%s ", node->vals.as_str);
            break;
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Although somewhat different, you may want to have a look at my answer on "generic" structs in C: [Writing a 'generic' struct-print method in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621027/writing-a-generic-struct-print-method-in-c/65621483#65621483)

Comment: Thank you for the your answer. if I was using an array of union it's because of the exercices I have given and I tried to send a simplified version which only had my problem but following this link you can see that there is a type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72806068/problem-with-double-linked-list-with-union-as-data-type-in-c anyway thank you your answer helped me